# write to file random numbers c#

Tags: c#, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random number generator not working the way I had planned (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c)

I have this code in c# but I get a result the same number, what is it wrong?

like a21, a21, a21....

```
        String c = "";
        int randomNumber = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            randomNumber = RandomNumber(0, 617);
            c += "a " + randomNumber + ", ";                    
        }
        file.WriteLine(c);



I am using this function

public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(min, max);
    }
```

Comment: the default seed is the current time which is in the default constructor -- since the current time between this loop is so quick, they all have the same seed.

Comment: how could I generate 20 different random numbers?

Comment: @cMinor: i've edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9040708/284240) to show you a way to create 20 random numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass the `Random` as parameter to your function. Although your function has no added value then anymore.

```
var rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    randomNumber = RandomNumber(rnd ,0, 617);
    c += "a " + randomNumber + ", ";                    
}

public static int RandomNumber(Random rnd, int min, int max)
{
    return rnd.Next(min, max);
}
```

Every time you do `new Random()` it is initialized using the clock. This means that in a tight loop you get the same value lots of times. You should keep a **single** `Random` instance and keep using Next on the same instance.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/768001/284240

**Edit**: i read in your comment that you want to create 20 unique numbers in the given range, here is one way using `HashSet<int>`:

```
HashSet<int> uniqueNumber = new HashSet<int>();
var rnd = new Random();
while(uniqueNumber.Count<20){
    var nextNum = rnd.Next(0, 617);
    uniqueNumber.Add(nextNum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The instance of `Random` needs to be instantiated once.

```
static Random random = new Random();
public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{        
    return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

In your implementation, `random` was getting instantiated with the system clock several times for one unit of time so you're using the exact same seed value for very few iterations, which for a single call means you'll always get the same value from `Next`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Random outside of RandomNumber i.e.

```
static Random random = new Random();
public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    return random.Next(min,max);
}
```